# Is PHPIDS enough for securing my website?

Tags: php, security, filtering, websecurity

I just found out about [PHPIDS](http://phpids.org/) and I have a couple of questions:

1. Can PHPIDS protect from automated sql injection attacks ?
2. Can it protect from DOS attacks?
3. Is it enough to be used on its own or must I use additional methods too?
4. Is it reliable?

Comment: No automated system will ever be able to protect you from yourself.  Write secure code and you'll be better off in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHPIDS (PHP-Intrusion Detection
>   System) is a simple to use, well
>   structured, fast and state-of-the-art
>   security layer for your PHP based web
>   application. The IDS neither strips,
>   sanitizes nor filters any malicious
>   input, it simply recognizes when an
>   attacker tries to break your site and
>   reacts in exactly the way you want it
>   to.

What that means is you STILL have to decide what to do with the:

1. Injection attack (drop / ignore / notify, etc;)
2. No it doesn't those are at the network level not application PHP layer.
3. This is a method of detecting, not santizing, filtering, etc; you still need your own code for protection.
4. Seems to be, why not try it. I am not aware of any 'graphs' to give you a statistical feed.

Comment: @newok ... right... but the question was *protect from* not *detect*.

Answer (score 0):

http://phpids.org/faq/

1) It can detect SQL injection.

2) No.

3) You will most likely need to have some additional method to complement what they provide.

4) Drupal uses it, so it fits their needs (most likely, yes.)